# UDP Connection Between Client and Server

Tags: c#, udpclient

Here is the server code of my program  this is working, but after it sends data it gets stuck. I need it to be refreshed and ready for sending data again.

Server code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
    try {
        String text = textBox1.Text;
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text,8899);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;

        while (true) {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
            string name = textBox2.Text;

            if (name == "") break;

            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);

            if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)==null) {               
                MessageBox.Show("Host not found");
            } else {                
                byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
                string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
                MessageBox.Show(job);
            }
        }
    } catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Restarting");
    }
```

Client code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        UdpClient subscriber = new UdpClient(8899);
        IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.2");
        subscriber.JoinMulticastGroup(addr);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            byte[] pdata = subscriber.Receive(ref ep);
            string strdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pdata);
            MessageBox.Show(strdata);
            textBox1.Text = strdata;
            pass = strdata;
        }
        subscriber.DropMulticastGroup(addr);
    } catch {
        Refresh();
        MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
    }
}
```

The Server can send data to one client . **I want to send one client at a time.**  But after sending the data, the server gets stuck.

I need it do refresh and send data again for a client.

Comment: What do you mean with: it gets stuck? Is there an error or just hanging?

Comment: I cannot access buttons and any thing  i have to close it through task manager

Comment: You're waiting for a response, but UDP is stateless and data receipt is not guaranteed so if for whatever reason it sends it and it never arrived its not sorted out like TCP.. if you need guarenteed delivery, you need TCP

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code, from the server your sending data, then waiting for an answer. In the client, your just getting the data, but not sending anything back. And unless you provide timeout to the socket, it will wait indefinitely until something arrives.

Comment: I think that's the problem but  how to give a time out

Comment: I dont thing it's possible with UDPClient. Try the Socket class and extend from there...

Answer (score 0):

The udpc.Receive() Method on your server side, will Block Until a datagram receive from client.
UDP in not reliable. it means that server doesnt expect any ACK from other side. so you can simply remove this part of code. or if you need to ensure message arrival,  run a separate thread for each client as follow:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
    System.Threading.Thread Server_thread = new Thread(My_Send_Function);
    Server_thread .Start();
}

private void My_Send_Function() {   
    try {
        String text = textBox1.Text;
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text,8899);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;

        while (true) {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: ");
            string name = textBox2.Text;

            if (name == "") break;

            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);

            if (udpc.Receive(ref ep)==null) {
                MessageBox.Show("Host not found");
            } else {
                byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
                string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
                MessageBox.Show(job);
            }
        }
    } catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Restarting");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use udpc.Receive() in the main UI thread (inside button1_Click). If you do, your aplication will hang until something arrives. Using a timeout isn't a solution either. The application will just hang until the timeout expires. Instead You must use a multiple threads. You can do so by using BeginReceive instead of Receive or by explicitly creating a new thread and using Receive there. If you google for "asynchronous udp sockets in c#" or something like that, then you will find plenty of examples on how to set it up correctly.